# Fix the position of one bubble in d3 pack layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bubble-chart

I'm building a bubble chart using D3 js (v5), to show some results of a research.
Basically I have a JSON with the total as the root and the children as each result.

One of the results must be highlighted and be positioned at the top center of the circle.
I managed to show this result there, but the other bubbles are overlapping (probably because I changed the position provided by the D3 hierarchy algorithm).

Is it possible to programmatically fix the position of only one bubble (the blue bubble in my example) and reposition the other bubbles, in order to not let them overlap each other?

[JFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcarvalho/wm8qz4cy/19/)

```js
const data = {
  name: 'Total',
  size: 1999999,
  children: [{
      name: 'Result A',
      size: 69936,
    },
    {
      name: 'Result b',
      size: 45000,
    },
    {
      name: 'Result C',
      size: 250000,
    },
    {
      name: 'Result D',
      size: 426791,
    },
    {
      name: 'Result E',
      size: 56000,
    },
    {
      name: 'Result F',
      size: 61050,
    },
    {
      name: 'Result G',
      size: 30000,
    },
  ],
};

// Fix this bubble at the top
const FIXED_BUBBLE_NAME = 'Result b';

const GREEN = '#90E0C2';
const BLUE = '#73A1FC';

const GRAPH_DIMENSIONS = {
  WIDTH: 234,
  HEIGHT: 234,
  PADDING: 10,
};

const buildDataTree = () => {
  const packLayout = d3
    .pack()
    .size([
      GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.WIDTH,
      GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.HEIGHT,
    ])
    .padding(GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.PADDING);

  const rootNode = d3
    .hierarchy(data)
    .sum((d) => d.size)
    .sort((a, b) => {
      return b.value - a.value;
    })

  return packLayout(rootNode);
};

const getSvgRoot = () => {
  return d3
    .select('#graph-container')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('id', 'graph-container-svg')
    .attr('width', GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.WIDTH + GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.PADDING)
    .attr('height', GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.HEIGHT + GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.PADDING)
    .style('overflow', 'visible');
};


const rootNodeDataTree = buildDataTree();

const svgRoot = getSvgRoot();

const node = svgRoot
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(
    d3
    .nest()
    .key((d) => d.id)
    .entries(rootNodeDataTree.descendants()),
  )
  .join('g')
  .selectAll('g')
  .data(d => d.values)
  .join('g');

node
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', (d) => d.r)
  .attr('cx', (d) => {
    // if it is the selected bubble it must be at the center
    if (d.data.name === FIXED_BUBBLE_NAME) {
      return GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.WIDTH / 2 + d.r / 2;
    }
    return d.x + GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.PADDING;
  })
  .attr('cy', (d) => {
    // if it is the selected bubble it must be at the center
    if (d.data.name === FIXED_BUBBLE_NAME) {
      return d.r + GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.PADDING * 2;
    }
    return d.y + GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.PADDING;
  })
  .attr('cursor', 'pointer')
  .attr('stroke', (d) => (d.children ? GREEN : ''))
  .attr('stroke-width', (d) => (d.children ? 2 : 0))
  .attr('fill-opacity', (d) => (d.children ? 0.24 : 1))
  .attr('fill', (d) => {
    if (d.data.name === FIXED_BUBBLE_NAME) {
      return BLUE;
    } else {
      return GREEN;
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="graph-container">

</div>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with d3 force simulation? Right after the packing calculation, I would run a force simulation with collision detection fixing the node that you want, so the simulation should re arrange the other nodes

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but I'll take a look, thanks for the tip @GuillermoGarcia

Comment: I will give it a try and will let you know

Comment: Do you expect to have an important number of circles? Rotating the whole chart so that the blue circle gets on top would be a simple solution.

Comment: @Mehdi I was trying just that before Guilhermo's answer haha 
I was trying to always put the blue bubble on the sides and rotate the circle from the bubble position to the top. It would work indeed. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with my suggestion: https://jsfiddle.net/9r8kt1e0/1/

The force simulation code is:

```
const simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation(allNodes.filter( (d) => d.depth !== 0))
  .force("collide",d3.forceCollide(d => { return d.r;}))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(0))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.WIDTH/2+10, GRAPH_DIMENSIONS.HEIGHT/2))
  .force("bound", (alpha) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < allNodes.length; ++i) {
      n = allNodes[i];
      n.x = pythag(n.r, n.y, n.x);
      n.y = pythag(n.r, n.x, n.y);
    }
  })
  .stop();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  simulation.tick();
}
```

Notice that we are passing a custom force called `bound`, this one should take care of keeping the nodes inside the parent circle.

That solves the overlapping, you would have to play a little with the forces according to your needs.

As per the documentation, a force is a function that modifies the nodes' position, you can have multiple forces, so hopefully, playing a little bit with the forces should solve your problem.

I hope it helps.